# Select sum of column and display top 3 MAX Sum with limit LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have bellow snippet table

[image: table]

Here i have to sum vote top 3 values.

Suppose `product_id` `3030` have sum of `vote` column is `8.1` and the `3671` `sum` is `5.2`

here i have to get top 3 product_id which have max sum like bellow example output.

here max sum `product_id` id `3030` have `sum` `8.1` and second is `3671` have `sum` `5.2`

I Have tried bellow query but it not showing top 3 `product_id` Max Top 3 of sum vote.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(vote) AS 'meta_sum',product_id FROM rating GROUP BY product_id ASC LIMIT 3") OR DIE(mysql_error())
```

Comment: order by meta_sum desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(vote) AS 'meta_sum', product_id 
FROM rating 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY 'meta_sum' DESC LIMIT 3
```

The above query will return the top `3` products having the greatest `SUM(vote)` values.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it will return 3 products having the greatest SUM(vote), not necessarily the 'top 3', as 'top' is undefined

Comment: in my i need to use meta_sum instead of 'meta_sum' to get top 3 product_id